# flink native k8s override log4j-console.properties

Tags: apache-flink

Flink version 1.13.

I want to add some logging properties, how to override `/opt/flink/conf/log4j-console.properties` using native k8s deployment?

Flink has already mount `/opt/flink/conf` using configMap, and this configMap contains other files like 'flink-conf.yaml', I don't want to override them. Just want to override `/opt/flink/conf/log4j-console.properties`.

Comment: are you using this tutorial https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/deployment/resource-providers/standalone/kubernetes/#appendix ? Why can\t you just edit the properties at `log4j-console.properties` on the file `flink-configuration-configmap.yaml`?

Comment: i use https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/deployment/resource-providers/native_kubernetes/